# How can I move only a certain body part of humanoid with cursor in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example a humanoid is standing still and one hand is grabbed with the cursor and cursor is moved around to make the humanoid do a waving motion. In this case the hand and the arm will only be moved but the rest of the body stays still.

How can I achieve this? How do I add a collider between each joint? or do I need to use ragdoll mechanics? I have no idea how to achieve this. If someone could send me in the right direction. I just need to basically be able to turn a humanoid in to a puppet where any parts can be grabbed and moved with the cursor.

Comment: What you need is called Inverse Kinematics (IK). You can see the manual page about it here: [Inverse Kinematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)

Comment: I can really recommend [SAFullBodyIK](https://github.com/Stereoarts/SAFullBodyIK) IK solver to you. It's a free git project and compares well to AssetStore solutions for money.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have managed to be able to move the hands and legs of a humanoid with Unity IK. But Unity IK only work with the legs and arms. Not torso or head. Looks like a Custom IK system needs to be used.